# if statement not echoing out html

Tags: php, html, if-statement, echo

For some reason I can't get my if-statement to echo out the HTML.

```
<?php
    $my_description = meta('description');
    if (!empty($my_description)): echo '<p class="description">'.$my_description.'</p>';
    echo '<br>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It only outputs the text, nothing else.

`meta('description')` is from a plugin in Wordpress that should output the text I placed in the backend. The above code ONLY outputs the following: `Lorem Ipsum...`

**Update:** I would like it to output:
`<p class="description">Lorem Ipsum...</p>`

Comment: So,you want the entire html?

Comment: what is `meta()`? clearly the if condition is not evaluating to true, so it depends on entirely what `meta` returns

Comment: I updated my post above. It outputs the text but not the HTML.

Comment: What text does it output? So `$my_description` is "Lorem Ipsum..." and it outputs that but not the `<p class="...`? sounds sort of impossible to me.

Comment: You are not really answering the question by @BhuvanRikka what exactly do you mean by 'output the text but not the HTML'? What kind of output you're expecting?

Comment: In the backend textarea, I literally put "Lorem Ipsum...". To echo that out, the plugin states to use <?php meta('description'); ?>, however I don't want that to appear if there is nothing in the textarea. I also want to have HTML wrapping that but not show if there's nothing there. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton that does make sense, what doesn't make sense is the actual behavior of your code.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton so you want to output the `<p class="description">Lorem Ipsum...</p>`, as TEXT (not HTML) so the user viewing your page sees it exactly as "<p class="description">Lorem Ipsum...</p>"?

Comment: No. In view source, I want it to output that.

Comment: But you're saying right now, in view source, it only shows `Lorem Ipsum...`, right? Try the code in my answer below and see if it works. That's really odd...

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is only outputting the text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20296/discussion-between-sachleen-and-christopher-burton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20296/discussion-between-sachleen-and-christopher-burton), we discovered that the `meta()` function was not returning the value we expect. The correct function is [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

```
<?php
    $my_description = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'description', 1);
    if (!empty($my_description)):
?>
    <p class="description"><?php echo $my_description; ?></p>
    <br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... sooo ugly, just do it like this:

```
<?php
echo !empty($my_description) ? '<p class="description">'.$my_description.'</p>' : '<br />';
?>
```

Use the ternary operator, don't use that messy `if` formatting...

Comment: That still outputs just the text.

Comment: @ChristopherBurton, not the fault of the code, make sure you have something to output first.